# Is there a way to set alpha attribute to child views as well as to parent view?

Tags: android, view, xml-drawable

I am developing app where I have set custom drawable to main layout with alpha attribute. But it sets alpha to whole view. and I wanted to set alpha to the only main layout. so that the text which will displayed normally without alpha effect. [Present Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xcQh.jpg)

The alpha effect is taken by whole view.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerLinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_with_bottom_curve"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/mainScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/scrollLinear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mainRelative"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtHeading"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Business Name"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/logo_orange"/>
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/paraOneRelative"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtHeading"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtParaOneBold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Some write up"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textStyle="normal"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `FrameLayout` as the base instead of `ConstraintLayout` and layer the `ScrollView` on top of a `View` (which has the translucent background). Something along the following lines should work,

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_with_bottom_curve" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollLinear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainRelative"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtHeading"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Business Name"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/logo_orange"/>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/paraOneRelative"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txtHeading"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtParaOneBold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Some write up"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the drawable on a view at the same level with the ScrollView

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/containerLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_with_bottom_curve"
        android:alpha="0.4"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

And you'll see that the text inside the `TextViews` no longer has the alpha.

Not related to the alpha issue, but the `ConstraintLayout` is useless here. Same for the constraints you set on it. The constraints should go on elements inside the `ConstraintLayout`. Basically you should have something like this:

```
FrameLayout
  ScrollView
    ConstraintLayout
      Views
```

Comment: ok. I did, but the alpha effect is still taken by both the textviews . and I want to set it to the drawable

Comment: @mi5pune I added some code example with what I meant. You'll see that the text no longer has the alpha

Answer (score 0):

you can try set background for scroll view and try alpha there

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mainRelative"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:alpha="0.4"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_with_bottom_curve">
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `ImageView` as a child of ConstraintLayout

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_with_bottom_curve"
    android:alpha="0.4"/>
```